# Trasformar Date a String e imprimirlo en un JDateChooser

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito de su ayuda, he buscado distintas soluciones en internet pero no he dado con la correcta. Mi pregunta es como puedo trasformar de un `Date` a `String` obteniendo la fecha desde mi base de datos MySQL?

La solución que encontré es utilizando:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date fecha = new Date();
String F = sdf.format(fecha);
```

Pero esa solución me trae la fecha de hoy y yo no necesito eso, necesito obtener la fecha que se encuentra almacenada en mi BD. En mi método `cargarDatos()` hago lo siguiente:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date fecha = new Date();
String F = sdf.format(fecha);
producto.setFechaVencimiento(F);
```

Mi atributo `fechaVencimiento` es de tipo `String` por eso necesito formatear la fecha de tipo `Date` a un `String` de esa forma logro formatearla correctamente pero solo obtengo la fecha actual.

Para traer la fecha de mi BD en mi método `obtener()` hago:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   Date fecha = new Date(rs.getDate("fechaVencimiento").getTime());
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   String f = sdf.format(fecha);
   System.out.println(f);
   jdcFechaVencimiento.setDateFormatString(f);
}
```

De esta forma si imprimo en consola mi objeto `f` obtengo la fecha almacenada que es ***20/06/2019*** hasta ahí todo bien! Mi problema es imprimir la fecha en mi `JDateChooser` que este formateada de esa misma manera en mi método `cargarDatos()`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date fecha = new Date();
String F = sdf.format(fecha);
producto.setFechaVencimiento(F);
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo algunos ejemplos creo que esta parte la puedes simplificar, aparte de que esta haciendo un paso mal, te dejo mi codigo y me comentas si te funciono.

```
       while (rs.next()) {             
            jdcFechaVencimiento.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Sirve para mostrar el formato en el date chooser
            jdcFechaVencimiento.setDate(new Date(rs.getDate("fechaVencimiento").getTime())); // la fecha como tal
        }
```

saludos!!

Comment: el codigo `jdcFechaVencimiento.setDate(new Date(rs.getDate("fechaVencimiento").getTime()));` me sirvió en el **while** pero me sigue dando error al querer mostrar la fecha en mi método **cargarDatos()** ES AHÍ donde tengo mi problema! Porque necesito obtener lo que hay en mi **JDateChooser** como lo hago en mi  **JTextField** por ej `producto.setProducto(jtxtProducto.getText());` nose si me explico..  El error que me sale es **no value specified for parameter 10** el cual pertenece a mi atributo **fechaVencimiento**